# Typeahead Click not working

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap

I'm trying to implment a typeahead function, the type ahead itself is working but when i click on the values nothing happens and the text input area remains empty.

Here's my code:

```
         self.element.find('#txtOP').typeahead({
          source: function (query, callback) {
            self.thCallback = callback;
            MegaControl.ProductionOrderFilter.findAll({ CodOP: self.element.find('#txtOP').val(), pageNum: self.cur_page, pageSize: self.page_size },
                function (data) {
                    self.thCallback(data.ProductionOrderList);
                });

        }, updater: function (item) {
            console.log("'" + item + "' selected.");
            return item;
        }, items: 5
        , minLength: 3

    });
```

What I am doing wrong?